# Should i create one page angular 6 application without use ng new myapp command?

Tags: html, angular

I need to create one page or two page using angular 6 but I don't want to use **ng new myapp** command. please guide me hows to use on one simple html page ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular create directory structure which will be required for transpiling your code from `typescript` to `javascript` bundles. Also for the compilation it needs many `npm` dependencies, which directly managed by `angular-cli`. So you always should use `angular-cli` i.e. `ng new myapp`.

If you are just prototyping, you can use https://stackblitz.com/ which provided all VS code functionality in browser without any setup.

Comment: we will not create angular 6 application in HTML page. Like as angularjs 1 version.
Right ? if you have any demo then plz share with me in html page.

Comment: No. The framework is completely changed since `Angular2`. Let it be one page or 100 pages, you'll need to create it with `ng new`. Also if you see multiple files, that doesn't mean there are multiple pages. Please refer angular documentation or online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official  [angular tutorial.](https://v6.angular.io/tutorial)

Angular is built upon the concept of single page applications.

So if you want to create an application with 2 pages, what you need to do is creating two components (using *ng generate component* command) and switch between them using [routing](https://v6.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5). Follow the documentation.

Comment: yes u r right  but i donot want to added more files . I need to add one or two pages in other project whose made in other language so I don't want to add more file in it. if possible angular 6 using cdn file with componet ?